# Adding a subscripts for P (price) in equation

Tags: regression, statistics, r

I made the following equation for a hedonic model. When I sent it to my teacher to check if it was fine, she told me that I should add subscripts for P so that we know by what it varies. I don't get it to be honest, where should i add these subscripts? If any of you have a suggestion or could explain, please do.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write:
$$
P_{i,j,k} = f(L_i,S_j, E_k).
$$

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was thinking, I just wanted to be sure.